# finding cartesian equations of parametric equations

Tags: parametric

find the Cartesian equation for the parametric equation 
$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} \text{ and } y=\frac{t}{1-t}$$

I tried cross multiplying but I cant seem to find the equation in terms of $t$ to substitute.

Comment: Hint: solve for $t$ (in terms of $x$) from the equation for $x$ and then substitute it in the one for $y$.

Comment: It looks to me that $x^2-y$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$y = \frac{t}{1-t} = \frac{1-(1-t)}{1-t} = \frac{1}{1-t} - 1$$
and since $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$ we have that $x^2 = \frac{1}{1-t} = y + 1$. So $y = x^2 - 1$ is the equation you're looking for.